# List Autodesk Construction Cloud Hubs

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I want to list all Files for a User, similar to what we have in Autodesk Construction Cloud:

[image: ACC Files listing]

This file is inside a project called *Varese* but to get all Projects first you need to list all Hubs.

Browsing the API docs I found the Hubs API: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/

After retrieving a valid token using your JavaScript library forge-apis, and including the access token in the `Bearer` I made two requests:

```
    const userResponse = await axios.get(
      "https://api.userprofile.autodesk.com/userinfo",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${credentials.access_token}`,
        },
      },
    );
    const hubsResponse = await axios.get(
      "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${credentials.access_token}`,
        },
      },
    );
```

Getting 200 from `userResponse` proved that the access token works, because I got back my user data:

```
user {
  sub: 'QJ3HRMKNJ8UG',
  name: 'AkosK',
  given_name: 'Akos',
  family_name: 'K',
  preferred_username: 'akosk',
  email: 'example@example.com',
  email_verified: true,
  profile: 'https://profile.autodesk.com',
  picture: 'https://images.profile.autodesk.com/default/user_Y220.png',
  locale: 'en-',
  updated_at: 1696555555
}
```

The call to `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs` also returned 200 but had the following in the response:

```
{
  warnings: [
    {
      Id: null,
      HttpStatusCode: '403',
      ErrorCode: 'BIM360DM_ERROR',
      Title: 'Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM US.',
      Detail: "You don't have permission to access this API",
      AboutLink: null,
      Source: null,
      meta: null
    },
    {
      Id: null,
      HttpStatusCode: '403',
      ErrorCode: 'BIM360DM_ERROR',
      Title: 'Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.',
      Detail: "You don't have permission to access this API",
      AboutLink: null,
      Source: null,
      meta: null
    }
  ]
}
```

When I'm authorizing access to my autodesk account these are the permissions that my app is requesting:

[image]

In my APS app, all 13 APIs are selected.

What am I missing here?